# IllegalStateException when adding fragment in response to a screen lock

Tags: android, android-fragments

Firstly, I believe this is not a duplicate question, although the solution for the error has been asked a lot of times. I have tried atleast 5 different solutions but they either don't change anything or make things worse. I want to pause the activity when the screen is locked/focus changed and allow the user to unpause the activity when the app is opened again.

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (!hasFocus && pauseFragment == null) {
        exercisePlayPause(isPaused, workoutExerciseNum);
        isPaused = !isPaused;
    }
}
```

exercisePlayPause calls the following method

```
public void PassExerciseNum(int exerciseNum, Boolean isPaused) {
    if (!isPaused) {
        pauseFragment = new PauseFragment();
        pauseFragment.getExNum(exerciseNum);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.aworkout_layout, pauseFragment, "pause").commit();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(pauseFragment).commit();
        pauseFragment = null;
        exercisePlayPause(true, exerciseNum);
    }
}
```

This works fine when the home button is pressed or some other app is activated or the notification bar is clicked. But when the screen is locked then I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1411)
                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1429)
                                                                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:687)
                                                                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:663)
```

The offending line is `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.aworkout_layout`. I am pausing few processes when any event that makes the user move away from the app. And when the user comes back to the app, he/she can resume from there. Hence, I am not destroying the activity. I have tried using `commitAllowingStateLoss()` but that makes me lose data for the paused processes and becomes a bit messy.

So in short the question is how to make a fragmenttransaction happen before onSaveInstanceState is triggered when the screen lock button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity's orientation was `sensorLandscape`. When a screen locks it converts the screen to portrait and when the screen is unlocked it starts from a portrait mode and then becomes landscape. Hence, `onDestroy` was called when screen is locked. And when the screen is unlocked, `onCreate` gets called. This orientation change overrides the activity's orientation set in manifest. What happens when this forceful orientation happens can be controlled by adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>` to the manifest. This prevents onDestroy being called and the "illegalStateException" can be avaoided.